# Converting InputStream.read() to numbers (not integers)

Tags: java, inputstream

I've been struggling to get a part of my program working. After about a week of trial and error I don't think I'm able to do this without any help.

Here's the case:
I've written an application which, using Sockets, reads data from a device over `TCP`. All the data sent by the device is represented as bytes, not as strings. Whenever I google on `InputStream`, all I get is "How to convert `InputStream` to String".

Currently I'm able to read the data from the `InputStream` into an `ArrayList<Integer>`. However, these are Integers, and not decimals.

Here's an example of a (UNIX) `TimeStamp` sent by the device, read in integers:

0 0 1 80 59 165 176 64 (edited, copied 1 byte too many)

I've tried a lot here, and have not yet succeeded in converting these to a correct UNIX timestamp. It should be translated to **1444109725 (which is 10/06/2015 @ 5:35am (UTC))**.

Anyone who could help me out? Thanks in advance!

-- Edit --

Thanks to all the answers below I've been able to create a working 'parser' for the incoming data. All I had to do was convert the bytes/integers to Long values. As my incoming data consists of multiple values with different lengths it's not possible to read it all as Long, so I had to iterate over te data, grab for example the 8 bytes/integers for the timestamp and use this method to create a readable unix timestamp:

```
public long bytesToLong(int[] bytes) { 
long v = 0 ; 
for (int i : bytes) { 
v = (v << 8) | i; 
} return v; 
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Read the numbers as bytes and assemble the long accordingly (bit-shift operators).

Comment: That's *9* bytes... that seems unlikely to all be a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick replies! I've tried too much already, I'm probably not doing it right. I've tried converting the values to HEX (which works), but I'm not able to convert them to correct decimals to assemble a timestamp.  @Thomas could you please show a simple example of this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

> It should be translated to 1444109725

Well, I suspect it should *actually* be translated to 1444109725760, which is what the bytes represent when read as a big-endian 64-bit integer. You then treat that as *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch (rather than seconds).

Fortunately, this is trivial to do: use `DataInputStream`, and call `readLong`. It would be slightly trickier if this were little-endian... but if your format is basically big-endian, you should do as much as you can using `DataInputStream`... it'll make your life much simpler.

Comment: You are correct, I've stripped the last 3 digits in my manual conversion due to them not being used in the timestamp converter. I will try to fiddle around with DataInputStream and readLong and post any results here

Comment: @Someone: You don't need to fiddle with it - you construct a `DataInputStream` wrapping your `InputStream`, call `readLong` on it, and you'll get 1444109725760. You can divide by 1000 then if you need to.

Comment: I think this only works when the data is a timestamp (or any other Long). For me, there's loads more besides the timestamp (which was only an example). Using the answer of @KDM I've been able to create a method which can accept a small portion of the stream (in bytes) and translate it into a Long which is needed in most cases.

Comment: @Someone: Well `readLong` does this for 8 bytes, yes. Then there's `readInt` for 4 bytes, and `readShort` for 2 bytes. I'd be surprised if you found other lengths in a network protocol, other than in very specialized situations.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer, using `DataInputStream` is the best way to go. If you want to get the value by hand:

```
package snippet;

public class FindLong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] bytes = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 80, 59, 165, 176, 64 } ;

        long v = 0 ;
        for (int i : bytes) {
            v = (v << 8) | i;
        }
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Prints `1444109725760`.

Comment: This helped a lot, I've created a simple method using your code which shows the correct timestamp now! `public long bytesToLong(int[] bytes) {
        long v = 0 ;
        for (int i : bytes) {
            v = (v << 8) | i;
        }
        return v;
    }`